# Is there a number $n$ such that $2^n$ is divisible by $31$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Every non prime number can be represented as a product of prime numbers. I don't know much about number theory, so could you please tell me if there's a number $2^n$ that is divisible by $31$?

Comment: No, the only factors of $2^n$ are powers of $2$.

Answer (score 0):

No. Since every integer $n>1$ has a unique factorization $n = p_1^{a_1}p_2^{a_2}...p_k^{a_k}$, where all the $p_i$'s are primes, and any number $t = 2^n$ has a prime factorization $t = 2^n$, all factors of $t$ must be powers of $2$, therefore $31$ is not a factor of $t$.